# C# console application stdin/stdout redirection

Tags: c#, console, pinvoke, stdout

I have an interesting (read: frustrating) problem kicking off a console application from a C# WPF app and redirecting its stdin and stdout.

It is mostly up and working but I seem to end up not getting some data from stdout as soon as I start redirecting stdin.

I'll clarify with an example. If I don't set hStdInput in the STARTUPINFO structure, when I start the child process I receive the following:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.0
connecting to: test
local:PRIMARY>
```

Once I set hStdInput however, I just get this:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.0
connecting to: test
```

I know that the BackgroundWorker processing stdout is still functioning because if I send something to the process on stdin, it responds accordingly.

```
use TestDB
switched to db TestDB
```

So, this is how I create the process:

```
_processInfo = new ProcessInfo();

bool ok = false;

SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sattr = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
sattr.bInheritHandle = 1;
unsafe
{
    sattr.lpSecurityDescriptor = null;
}
sattr.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(sattr);

IntPtr hWrite;
ok = CreatePipe(out _hReadStdOut, out hWrite, ref sattr, 0);
ok = SetHandleInformation(_hReadStdOut, HANDLE_FLAGS.INHERIT, 0);
IntPtr hRead;
ok = CreatePipe(out hRead, out _hWriteStdIn, ref sattr, 0);
ok = SetHandleInformation(_hWriteStdIn, HANDLE_FLAGS.INHERIT, 0);

var startInfo = new StartupInfo
{
    dwFlags = 0x0001 | 0x0100,
    wShowWindow = 0,
    hStdOutput = hWrite,
    hStdError = hWrite,
    hStdInput = hRead // If this is IntPtr.Zero, I get everything from stdout
};

SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES pSec = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
pSec.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(pSec);
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES tSec = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
tSec.nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(tSec);

unsafe
{
    ok = CreateProcess(
        null,
        pathToExeAndArgs,
        ref pSec,
        ref tSec,
        true,
        0,
        IntPtr.Zero,
        null,
        ref startInfo,
        out _processInfo);
}
```

I have a BackgroundWorker processing stdout on DoWork which reads the pipe like so:

```
success = ReadFile(
    _hReadStdOut,
    bufPtr,
    1024,
    &read,
    IntPtr.Zero);
```

I'm not using the .Net Process class because it didn't obtain data from stdout until the console application sent a newline, so I didn't get the prompt back in that case either.

Any help with this greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: As an aside, there's no need for unsafe code here, and you can pass `NULL` for `pSec` and `tSec`.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the following explains what you have observed:

- When you don't define `hStdInput` the child process uses the standard input device attached to the console. The child process detects that standard input is an interactive console device and writes a prompt.
- When you do define `hStdInput` the child process detects that the standard input is a pipe and so neglects to write a prompt. After all, what's the point of prompting a non-interactive input device?

The child process will use `GetFileType(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE))` to detect what type of device is attached to the standard input. A value of `FILE_TYPE_CHAR` indicates a console. When you attach a pipe to the standard input then the standard input file type will be `FILE_TYPE_PIPE`.

My conclusion is that everything is working as designed and intended.

Comment: That makes sense and has given me an avenue to explore. Thanks.